# Rails Error: `method_missing': undefined method `register_middleware'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rubygems, rake-task, rails-console

On Rails, I'm trying to rake a new task I just created and it's giving me an undefined method error:

```
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `register_middleware' for #<Faraday::Connection:0x007f8773f41288>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday.rb:99:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:41:in `build_conn'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:30:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `configure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:86:in `<module:Balanced>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/Stephanie/Desktop/Pixiboard/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Stephanie/Desktop/Pixiboard/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also get a similar error when trying to run the command "rails console" (to see if there's anything wrong with my task):

```
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday.rb:99:in `method_missing': undefined method `register_middleware' for #<Faraday::Connection:0x007f986c506700> (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:41:in `build_conn'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced/client.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:29:in `configure'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:86:in `<module:Balanced>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/balanced-0.8.1/lib/balanced.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/Stephanie/Desktop/Pixiboard/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me on what to do?
(I'm on Rails 3.2.12)

Answer (score 2):

balanced-ruby is not yet compatible with faraday 0.9.0. See more [balanced-ruby/issues/173](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/issues/173)

and try to use faraday 0.8.6 in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.8.6'
```